# Covariance calculation with a nested loop in OpenMP

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have a core piece of code used to compute covariances between a model state and observations that will be run hundreds of thousands of times, and I'd like to use OpenMP to speed things up. The current implementation doesn't seem to speed things up as much as I hoped. There is a nested loop where a covariance is computed. N is large (around 10^4), and M is relatively small (around 10^2). The inner loop computes two sums and divides one sum by the other. Any suggestions on how I could speed this up?

```
  xa     = ...
  hxens  = ...
  istate = ...

  !$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(SHARED) PRIVATE(iupdt, iobs, mem_count, iens)                                            
  !$OMP DO
  do iupdt = 1,N                                        
     mem_count = 0

     do iens = 1,M
           cij(iupdt) = cij(iupdt) + xa(istate,iens) * hxens(iupdt,iens)   
           mem_count = mem_count + 1
     end do
     cij(iupdt) = cij(iupdt)/(mem_count-1)          
  end do
  !$OMP END DO          
  !$OMP END PARALLEL
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Try to transpose the hxens and xa arrays to have iens the left-most index

Comment: Thanks Anthony - I will give that a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue in your code is the access order for arrays `xa` and `hxens`. However, the code would behave much better if the `iupdt` and `iens` loops were swapped. This is quite easy to do if the final division of `cij` is removed from the `iupdt` loop, and set in a new loop of its own. Also, it has to be noticed that the accumulation of `mem_count` is useless since the result will always be `M`.

For the sake of being able to compile the code, I placed the snippet in a subroutine. This is what it looks like in the end:

```
subroutine covariance( xa, hxens, cij, istate, N, M )
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in)             :: istate, N, M 
    double precision, intent(in)    :: xa(N,M), hxens(N,M)
    double precision, intent(inout) :: cij(N)

    integer          :: iupdt, iens
    double precision :: ratio, xaiens

    ratio = 1.d0 / (M-1)
    !$omp parallel private( xaiens, iens, iupdt )
    !$omp do
    do iens = 1,M
        xaiens = xa(istate,iens)
        !$omp simd
        do iupdt = 1,N
             cij(iupdt) = cij(iupdt) + xaiens * hxens(iupdt,iens)   
        end do
        !$omp end simd
    end do
    !$omp end do
    !$omp do simd
    do iupdt = 1,N
        cij(iupdt) = cij(iupdt) * ratio          
    end do
    !$omp end do simd
    !$omp end parallel
end subroutine covariance
```

A few remarks:

- All memory accesses are now linear, which is good
- However, `cij` which was previously probably only accessed once (because cached during the `iens` loops), is now accessed `iens` times. This is potentially very bad. However, since you said `N` is around 10000, that means that `cij` is around 80KB which will fit in cache. So this shouldn't have any consequence.
- The innermost loop is now trivially vectorisable. Moreover, it is well suited for the use of a fused multiply and add operation, permitting to exploit the full potential of the processor. I've put a `omp simd` directive to reinforce that, but you can remove it if your compiler doesn't support it. In any case, the vectorisation case is so obvious that I doubt the compiler needs it. Likewise for the last loop.
- The computations being so limited and the actual data fitting in cache, I'm not certain that the OpenMP parallelisation will be so effective/necessary. I encourage you to try the code with and without it, and to remove all or parts of it, should it proves counter-effective. I've put all of what can reasonably be set here, but do not hesitate to prune what needs to be.

Comment: I marked this answer as accepted because I think you got to the heart of the issue: switching the order of loops. It makes a lot of sense. As I mentioned in the other comment, ratio is potentially different for each iupdt, but this is easily fixed by computing it once offline and using 

    `cij(iupdt) = cij(iupdt) * ratio(iupdt)`
Thank you very much!

Comment: I also really appreciate your insight into the potential that this cannot be improved much with OpenMP. This in fact was what I was seeing - I saw a large speedup with MPI, but not when using hybrid MPI/OpenMP, which was puzzling to me. If cij can fit into the cache, this would make perfect sense. Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

1) You can remove mem_count : the sum is always M.

2) You can unroll the outer loop: it you have a Haswell CPU, you will be able to do vectorized FMA. Aligning the arrays on a 32-byte boundary will improve performance using compiler options or directives.

3) If you can go to single precision where you can gain an extra factor of two. You can accumulate in single precision and divide in double precision (be careful if xa * hxens is always of the same sign, you will be very imprecise...)

4) You can compute only once 1.d0/(dble(M)-1.d0) to avoid doing div operations which are expensive.

Where you allocate your arrays, if you have the intel compiler:

```
  !DIR$ ATTRIBUTES ALIGN : 32 :: cij, hxens
```

Then,

```
  n8 = (n/8)*8                             
  f = 1.d0/(dble(M)-1.d0)

  !$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(SHARED) PRIVATE(iupdt, iobs, iens, l)       
  !$OMP DO
  do iupdt = 1,n8,8                                        

     do iens = 1,M 
       do l=0,7
         cij(iupdt+l) = cij(iupdt+l) + xa(istate,iens) * hxens(iupdt+l,iens)   
       end do
     end do

     do l=0,7
       cij(iupdt+l) = cij(iupdt+l) * f
     end do

  end do
  !$OMP END DO

  !$OMP END PARALLEL

  do iupdt = n8+1,n                                        
     do iens = 1,M
        cij(iupdt) = cij(iupdt) + xa(istate,iens) * hxens(iupdt,iens)   
     end do
     cij(iupdt) = cij(iupdt)*f          
  end do
```

Comment: Hi Anthony, thanks! This is helpful. I would rather avoid these kinds of specialized optimizations as they make the code harder to read. I have dealt with too many SIMD codes to be wary of this... <shudder>. But I will definitely give it a try! It turns out that I oversimplified my example - mem_count is actually dependent on the value of xa(istate,iens). But I will take the idea to divide outside of the loop. Thank you again!